# Using grep to extract text from console. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have the following output after running the file `test.sh` on a Bash console

```
{ "id" : "0cba-2dbc-11e4-8c2c-bb68" }
```

I want just get the value of `id` using the grep or the egrep command. This is what i have tried so far:

```
test.sh | grep -E "(: \".*\" })"
```

This just print back the same output as above. So next i tried grouping by adding parenthesis `(.*)` around the value i want to save:

```
test.sh | grep -E "(: \"(.*)\" })"
```

But i am still ending up with the same result.

Is there any way to just get the value: 0cba-2dbc-11e4-8c2c-bb68 printed without using python?

Comment: Trying to parse JSON with `awk`/`grep`/`sed` is always a bad idea as they don't "understand" the JSON format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another `awk`

```
echo '{ "id" : "0cba-2dbc-11e4-8c2c-bb68" }' | awk -F\" '$2=="id" {print $4}'
0cba-2dbc-11e4-8c2c-bb68
```

Comment: +1 works.. but the other dude answered first. Is there any difference between this awk and the one from @anubhava? Or is one more flexible than the other? Im not familiar with awk

Comment: @Jai Both `awk` works.  Mine is some shorter.  I do set the field separator to `"` (split the data by double quote), then just print the forth field.  Try to change the `$4` to  `$1` or `$2` or `$3` etc to see what you get as output from the splitting.

Answer (score 4):

You should use adequate tools to work with JSON data, *e.g.* [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) (lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor) as **trying to parse JSON with `awk`/`grep`/`sed` is always a bad idea** as they don't "understand" the JSON format.

```
echo '{ "id" : "0cba-2dbc-11e4-8c2c-bb68" }' | jq '.id'
"0cba-2dbc-11e4-8c2c-bb68"
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj bold is used to emphasis

Comment: @Jai ok, so refer to others answers and be careful

Answer (score 3):

you need `-o` option, try this line:

```
grep -Po '"id"\s*:\s*"\K[^"]*'
```

the `\K` here is something **like** look behind. It supports un-fixed number of chars.  So,  translate it into english:

**only** (`-o`) give  me the text after `"id" (any number of spaces):(any number of spaces)"` till the next `"`. which is your id value.

`-P` means, using `PCRE`

Comment: I would not encourage the use of 1. `grep` for this kind of task as user will have to awkwardly reimplement JSON support 2. `-P` is an experimental feature.

Comment: @ÉdouardLopez you can downvote the answer, no problem. but for your comment. 1) read the title of the question, **grep** is clearly there. I let OP know, why his grep line won't work. 2) for json. I don't see single "json" in OP's question, you can guess it was json.  but you cannot certainly say, it is json, unless OP say it is. 3). -P is handy but not all grep has it, true. how about `jq`? I don't have that installed.

Comment: @Kent 1. the restriction to `grep` was not clearly stated at first 2. the accepted answer use `awk`, 3. I prefer a clear dependency over an ambiguous/experimental feature.

Answer (score 1):

Just pipe your output to:

```
some-command | awk -F '[{}: ]+' '{gsub(/"/, "")} $2=="id"{print $3}'
0cba-2dbc-11e4-8c2c-bb68
```

Comment: Yes sure. This uses a custom field separator which is one or more of `[{}: ]` characters. Then `gsub` removes all double quotes. And finally `$2=="id"` is evaluating if `$3` is `id` and if true then it prints `$3` which is your string `0cba-2dbc-11e4-8c2c-bb68`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach.

```
echo '{ "id" : "0cba-2dbc-11e4-8c2c-bb68" }' | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/["]//g'
```

Returns

```
0cba-2dbc-11e4-8c2c-bb68
```